# Passing Parameters to and from a child window in CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have written a program using CefSharp that scrapes a web page.  When I began the project, I didn't realize that the web site made use of the now defunct showModalDialog function.  I really like CefSharp and don't want to have to use the .Net WebBrowser if I can help it.  I implemented the replacement for showModalDialog as an extension using a trimmed down version of the code found here :

https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog

I created the following showModalDialog.js and added it as a Resource:

```
(function () {
showModalDialog = function (url, arg, opt) {
    url = url || ''; //URL of a dialog
    arg = arg || null; //arguments to a dialog
    opt = opt || 'dialogWidth:300px;dialogHeight:200px'; //options: dialogTop;dialogLeft;dialogWidth;dialogHeight or CSS styles
    var caller = showModalDialog.caller.toString();
    var dialog = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('dialog'));
    dialog.setAttribute('style', opt.replace(/dialog/gi, ''));
    dialog.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="dialog-close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 4px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; outline: none;">&times;</a><iframe id="dialog-body" src="' + url + '" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>';
    document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;
    document.getElementById('dialog-close').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dialog.close();
    });
    dialog.showModal();
    //if using yield
    if (caller.indexOf('yield') >= 0) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            dialog.addEventListener('close', function () {
                var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
                document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                resolve(returnValue);
            });
        });
    }
    //if using eval
    var isNext = false;
    var nextStmts = caller.split('\n').filter(function (stmt) {
        if (isNext || stmt.indexOf('showModalDialog(') >= 0)
            return isNext = true;
        return false;
    });
    dialog.addEventListener('close', function () {
        var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
        document.body.removeChild(dialog);
        nextStmts[0] = nextStmts[0].replace(/(window\.)?showModalDialog\(.*\)/g, JSON.stringify(returnValue));
        eval('{\n' + nextStmts.join('\n'));
    });
    throw 'Execution stopped until showModalDialog is closed';
};
})();
```

I got it registered in CefSharp in the startup as follows:

```
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

            settings.RegisterExtension(new CefExtension("showModalDialog", Resources.showModalDialog));

            //Perform dependency check to make sure all relevant resources are in our output directory.
            Cef.Initialize(settings, shutdownOnProcessExit: true, performDependencyCheck: true);
```

So when showModalDialog is called from a web page, it pops up the dialog.  The problem is that it doesn't seem to pass the parameter correctly.  The page I am scraping sets up the showModalDialog as follows:

```
    function popupPanel() { 
        var args = new Array(document.getElementById("IDofElementToReceiveTheValue"));
        var url = '<url of the html for the popup>'
        var windowParam = 'resizable=yes;dialogWidth=975px;dialogHeight=750px;scrollbars=yes;status=no';
        showModalDialog(url,args, windowParam);
        return true;
    }
```

The popup displays a list of records with a select column.  When you click the link in the select column, this function fires:

```
function selectItem(keyvalue) {
    window.dialogArguments[0].value = keyvalue;
    window.close();
}
```

So when the showModalDialog is called, it creates an array containing one element that should receive the value of the record that is selected.  It passes this array as an argument to the showModalDialog.  The showModalDialog passes this array into the dialogArguments for the window of the popup.  When you select an item, it throws an error saying "there is no object at index 0 of null" and the window never closes (I assume this is because it never gets to that step due to the exception).  For some reason, when the selectItem function is called, the dialogArguments of the window is null.  The object is not making it from the initial setup for the call to showModalDialog to the selectItem function in the popup.  Can anyone shed any light on why this might be?  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Have you used `DevTools` to add a breakpoint, step into the function and see what's actually going on?

Comment: I didn't realize you could do that.  Do you by chance have a link to a page that describes how to do this?

Comment: Pretty much the same as `Chrome`, https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#debugging-javascript use the `browser.ShowDevTools()` extension method.

Comment: I have been using the Dev Tools extensively.  They are amazing.  It's the break points I didn't know about.  I will take a look at it.  It seems difficult to set break points when the code in the web page changes constantly.

Comment: I worked some more on this and have determined that the problem is that since the popup is created as an IFRAME, it uses .contentWindow.  Apparently the original showModalDialog uses .window since that is what the dialog acts on i.e. accessing window.dialogArguments and window.close function.  Is there any way to map these from the .contentWindow to the .window?